# ConvNN weird accuracy scores and accuracy plot

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Hi (on beggining i wanna say that i'm newbie at neural networks)!
I've been coding simple cats and dogs classifier in python. I'm using python with tensorflow. Type of NN is Conv. I trained couple times network and i'm getting low accuracy scores (50%) and accuracy plot look weird.[Loss plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szaea.png) [Accuracy plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PELTp.png). 
Here's neural net:

```
def create_net():
    weights, biases = init_weights_biases()

    l1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    l1 = maxpool2d(l1)

    l2 = conv2d(l1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    l2 = maxpool2d(l2)

    l3 = conv2d(l2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
    l3 = maxpool2d(l3)

    l4 = tf.reshape(l3, shape=[-1, weights['wfc'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    l4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l4, weights['wfc']), biases['bfc'])
    l4 = tf.nn.softmax(l4)
    l4 = tf.nn.dropout(l4, .5)

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(l4, weights['bout']), biases['bout'])
    return out

pred = create_net()
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=.001).minimize(cost)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

And here's how i train neural net:

```
for i in range(epochs):
    if previous_batch >= len(X_train):
        previous_batch = 0

    current_batch = previous_batch + batch

    X_train_i = X_train[previous_batch:current_batch]
    X_train_i = np.array(X_train_i).reshape(batch, 64, 64, 1)

    y_train_i = y_train[previous_batch:current_batch]
    y_train_i = np.array(y_train_i)

    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
        x: X_train_i,
        y: y_train_i
    })

    previous_batch += batch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not iterating through full dataset in each epoch. You are just using data of size `batch` in each iteration which I think is fairly low, like 100, 128, 256, etc. This might be the reason you are getting low accuracy scores.

For example consider the output of below training loop(same as yours) with some random data:

```
import numpy as np

epochs = 5
previous_batch = 0
X_train = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
batch = 128
y_train = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
for i in range(epochs):
    if previous_batch >= len(X_train):
        previous_batch = 0

    current_batch = previous_batch + batch
    print(previous_batch, current_batch)

    X_train_i = X_train[previous_batch:current_batch]
    y_train_i = y_train[previous_batch:current_batch]   
    print(i, X_train_i.shape, y_train_i.shape)

    previous_batch += batch
```

Output:

```
0 128
0 (128, 5) (128, 2) # epoch 0
128 256
1 (128, 5) (128, 2) # epoch 1
256 384
2 (128, 5) (128, 2) # epoch 2
384 512
3 (128, 5) (128, 2) # epoch 3
512 640
4 (128, 5) (128, 2) # epoch 4
```

Here, each iteration uses just 128 data samples from the entire dataset. In other words, we are not using entire dataset(X_train, y_train) in each iteration while training, which might lead to poor training results.

In order to run through your entire dataset in each iteration, do something like below:

```
for i in range(epochs):
    previous_batch = 0
    for j in range(len(X_train)//batch):
        current_batch = previous_batch + batch

        X_train_i = X_train[previous_batch:current_batch]
        X_train_i = np.array(X_train_i).reshape(batch, 64, 64, 1)

        y_train_i = y_train[previous_batch:current_batch]
        y_train_i = np.array(y_train_i)

        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
            x: X_train_i,
            y: y_train_i
        })

        previous_batch += batch
```